# Kann man »gegen« jemanden oder etwas diskriminieren?

Tags: word-choice, preposition

Ich bin soeben über folgenden Satz gestolpert:

> Zero-Rating untergräbt meine Wahlfreiheit und diskriminiert gegen einzelne Online-Dienste.

Nach meinem Kenntnisstand wird *gegen* in Kombination mit *diskriminieren* nur  zur Beschreibung eines Zustands verwendet:

> Das ist diskriminierend *gegen* viele Minderheiten. → Akkusativ
>
> Das ist diskriminierend  *gegenüber* vielen Minderheiten. →  Dativ

Auch der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/diskriminieren) erwähnt nirgends, dass *gegen* auch im aktiven Fall verwendet werden kann. Kann mir jemand eine Regel nennen, die das genauer beschreibt?

Wie einige der Kommentatoren bereits vermutet haben, stammt der Satz aus einer Übersetzung aus dem Englischen. Es handelt sich also vermutlich tatsächlich um einen *false friend*.

Comment: Also möchtest du wissen, ob *diskriminieren* auch im Aktiv anstatt nur im Zustandspassiv verwendet werden kann?

Comment: Das ist Unsinn. Das Wort bedeutet wörtlich übersetzt "absondern", "trennen", - Das kann man nicht "gegen" jemanden, sondern höchstens "von etwas" tun.

Comment: Interferenz mit englisch _discriminate against someone_ ‘jemanden benachteiligen’. Bei _diskriminieren_ ‘benachteiligen’ und _discriminate_ ‘unterscheiden’ handelt es sich um falsche Freunde.

Comment: „Gegen“ ist zumindest handlicher als „zu Ungunsten von“. Ich würde es aber auch nicht sagen.

Comment: @chirlu Allerdings kann _diskriminieren_ auch bloß ‚(ohne Wertung) unterscheiden / einteilen‘ heißen – oder konnte das wenigstens mal. Es fehlt noch der Hinweis, dass _anhand_ oder _mittels_ einer Eigenschaft diskriminiert werden kann.

Comment: @Crissov: Der Duden [sieht](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/diskriminieren) diese neutrale Bedeutung heute als beschränkt auf bestimmte Fachsprachen an, m.E. zu Recht.

Comment: @chirlu Ja, allerdings liest man gelegentlich auch außerhalb von Fachsprachen _positiv diskriminieren_ i.S.v. ‚ungleich behandeln‘. (Meine Liste der Präpositionen für die Eigenschaft war natürlcih nicht vollständig, bspw. geht auch _aufgrund_ oder _wegen_.)

Comment: Da eine Benachteilung immer eine Ungleichbehandlung ist leuchtet mir die Behauptung mit dem false friend nicht ein.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Klare Antwort: Nein. Diskriminieren heißt nach Duden entweder: **ungleich behandeln**. Ich behandle also Online-Dienste ungleich, ein zusätzliches *gegen* ist nicht nur überflüssig, sondern stört. Oder in der anderen Bedeutung **benachteiligen**, dann ist ein Akkusativ-Objekt gefragt.

Bei *diskriminierend* ist gar kein Objekt angebracht, entweder ist eine Handlungsweise diskriminierend oder nicht. Will man zum Ausdruck bringen, wer benachteiligt  wird, muss man auf *benachteiligt* ausweichen. Ich vermute stark, dass das angeführte *gegenüber* auch genau von diesem *benachteiligt* herrührt, weil hier das Vergleichsobjekt, das eben nicht benachteiligt ist, typischerweise mit einem *gegenüber* oder *im Vergleich zu* angeführt wird.

Comment: Stimme zu, scheint mit ein false friend zu sein (vgl. _discriminate against_)

Comment: Ich denke, man sollte anmerken, dass man sich "jemandem gegenüber diskriminierend verhalten" kann (oder beliebiges anderes Verb). Hier ist "diskriminierend" ein Adverb.

Comment: @Em1: Richtig, aber das ist keine Eigenschaft von _diskriminierend_. Ich kann mich auch jemandem gegenüber unhöflich verhalten, oder freundlich, oder neutral.